# `auto` variable declaration with multi-word fundamental types causes error

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

Is it possible to declare a variable with the auto keyword and a type name that is made of two or more words?

And if not, why not?

For example

`auto foo = unsigned int{0};`

Give the following compiler output

Clang:

`error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction`

GCC:

`error: expected primary-expression before 'unsigned'`

Comment: Why would you do something like this?? The whole idea of `auto` is *not* to write the type. If you want to declare something (for the first time, with type and all) you use the normal declaration `unsigned int foo = 0;`. If you follow this with an `auto bar = foo;` all should be good.

Comment: @Emil Vatai I agree, but is there a good reason why this isn't allowed when it works with other fundamental types? Is it too complex to parse? The question still stands even if it isn't 'best practice'.

Comment: No, this is very far from "best practice". What do you mean by "other fundamental types?" Try deleting `int` (the meaning/semantics of the program wont change because `unsigned` is the same as `unsigned int`) and see if it compiles. That should get you closer to the answer.

Comment: Looking at the 'Fundamental Types' page on cppreference.com. Something like `long double` wouldn't work in this situation, you could use the `L` suffix, or a cast, but I'm wondering why exactly is this syntax not allowed.

Comment: Ahh... ok, by mult-word you ment a type which described by multiple words... (I thought a type with size larger than a register). So, yeah, the parsing is the problem. What you are doing here is casting. Let me look up some official documentation.

Comment: Maybe there is a better phrase I could use there to avoid confusion.

Comment: See my answer, I hope that answers your "why?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For

```
auto foo = T{0};
```

to work, `T` has to be a *simple-type-specifier*.

From the [C++11 Standard/5.2.3 Explicit type conversion (functional notation)/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.type.conv#3)

> Similarly, a [*simple-type-specifier*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.type.simple#nt:simple-type-specifier) or *typename-specifier* followed by a [*braced-init-list*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/temp.res#nt:typename-specifier) creates a temporary object of the specified type direct-list-initialized ([[dcl.init.list]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.init.list)) with the specified [*braced-init-list*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/temp.res#nt:typename-specifier), and its value is that temporary object as a prvalue.

If you see the definition of [*simple-type-specifier*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.type.simple#nt:simple-type-specifier), `unsigned int` is not one of them.

You can use any of the following:

```
auto foo = 0U;
auto foo = (unsigned int)0;
auto foo = static_cast<unsigned int>(0);
```

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't!

Comment: @EmilVatai `auto foo = 0U` seems clean. Why not?

Comment: Yeah, that's the "most reasonable", but still I'd say you shouldn't do it. If you want a variable `foo` of type `unsigned int` with value `0`, the recommended way to go is `unsigned int foo = 0;`. The question was more with regard to why does this syntax work with types `int` (described by a single keyword) and not with `unsigned int` (described with multiple keywords).

Comment: @EmilVatai, thanks for the prod. I was able to find the references in the standard that explainswhy the OP's construct is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you want the compiler to group multiple things but it doesn't, you use parentheses to force it:

```
auto foo = (unsigned int)(0);
```

Note that as [@cpplearnern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4672588/cpplearner) points out, if you use curly braces instead, it counts as a [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) and is not legal C++, though is legal C99:

```
auto foo = (unsigned int){0}; /* Not legal C++, though GCC and Clang support it. */
```

In any case, a better solution is to use [integral literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal):

```
auto foo = 0u;
```

Comment: This is technically non-standard and compilers will warn you.

Comment: @cpplearner thanks for the feedback. Added that to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is probably here http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/ (section "Type casting").

And maybe this is even better: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast Under this link, you are using syntax (5):  `new_type { expression-list(optional) }`.

So if you have a space in your type name how will the compiler guess if `unsigned int {0}` is `(unsigned int) {0}` (what you meant probably), or is it `(unsigend (int {0}))` (which would be actually two conversions)... so you have to explicitly put the type name into parenthesis.

This would be important if you'd want to do `long unsigned {x}`, because then I'd result in

- `long` if it is interpreted as `long (unsigned {x})`
- `unsigned long` if it is interpreted as `(long unsigned){x}`